# Statement in trigger is not "picking up" the condition in its Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, triggers

so I'm currently working on a MySQL trigger. I'm trying to assign values to two variables when a new record is inserted. Below are the queries:

1. SET mssgDocNo = (SELECT Document_ID FROM CORE_MSSG WHERE Message_ID = new.MSSG_ID);
2. SET mssgRegime = (SELECT CONCAT (Regime_Type, Regime_Code) FROM T_DOC WHERE CD_Message_ID = new.MSSG_ID);;

For some reason, the second SQL query is not picking up the 'new.MSSG_ID' condition while the first query in same trigger recognizes it. I really can't figure out what seems to be the problem.

When I replace the 'new.MSSG_ID' with a hard-coded value from the database in the second query it seems to work. I doubt the 'new.MSSG_ID' is the problem because it works perfectly fine in the first query.

I've tried pretty much anything I could think of. Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Consider to post the DDL for the relevant tables and the whole trigger code, possibly along with some test data.

Answer (score 0):

I would write these more simply as:

```
SELECT mssgDocNo := Document_ID
FROM CORE_MSSG
WHERE Message_ID = new.MSSG_ID;

SELECT mssgRegime := CONCAT(Regime_Type, Regime_Code)
FROM T_DOC
WHERE CD_Message_ID = new.MSSG_ID;
```

The `SET` is not necessary.

I did make one other change that might make it work.  I removed the space after `CONCAT`.  Some versions of MySQL have trouble parsing spaces after function calls.